# Доработка раскрывающегося меню: переход по ссылке

Tags: jquery, javascript

Доброе время суток.
Помогите, пожалуйста, доработать скрипт.
Есть уже готовый для раскрывающегося меню, все отлично работает, но еще нужно, чтобы можно было переходить по ссылкам первого уровня, плюс по клику на них выезжало меню. Или, например, чтобы выезжало/заезжало по клику на плюсик/минусик.
Работающий пример, чтобы было понятней - http://pro-potolok.com/potolki/
Код скрипта:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('ul.nav ul, .news_sidebar ul ul').each(function(i) { // Check each submenu:
    if ($.cookie('submenuMark-' + i)) {  // If index of submenu is marked in cookies:
        $(this).show().prev().removeClass('collapsed').addClass('expanded'); // Show it (add apropriate classes)
       /* $("ul.nav li.level_1").after("<div class='li_shadow'></div>"); */
    }else {
        $(this).hide().prev().removeClass('expanded').addClass('collapsed'); // Hide it
    }
    $(this).prev().addClass('collapsible').click(function() { // Attach an event listener
        var this_i = $('ul.nav ul, .news_sidebar ul ul').index($(this).next()); // The index of the submenu of the clicked link
        if ($(this).next().css('display') == 'none') {
            $(this).next().slideDown(200, function () { // Show submenu:
                $(this).prev().removeClass('collapsed').addClass('expanded');
                cookieSet(this_i);
            });
        }else {
            $(this).next().slideUp(200, function () { // Hide submenu:
                $(this).prev().removeClass('expanded').addClass('collapsed');
                cookieDel(this_i);
                $(this).find('ul').each(function() {
                    $(this).hide(0, cookieDel($('ul.nav ul, .news_sidebar ul ul').index($(this)))).prev().removeClass('expanded').addClass('collapsed');
                });
            });
        }
    return false; // Prohibit the browser to follow the link address
    });
});
});
function cookieSet(index) {
    $.cookie('submenuMark-' + index, 'opened', {expires: null, path: '/'}); // Set mark to cookie (submenu is shown):
}
function cookieDel(index) {
    $.cookie('submenuMark-' + index, null, {expires: null, path: '/'}); // Delete mark from cookie (submenu is hidden):
}
```

Comment: Вам ответят на много быстрее, если вы выложите свой код на http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Я на этом форуме новичек. Вот ссылочка - http://jsfiddle.net/3VWw4/6/ Там упрощенней, оставила только основную работу меню.

Comment: непонятно, вроде по ссылкам переходит... и в смысле как это чтобы и переходило и чтобы раскрывалось ? типа надо чтобы была кнопка на этих всех меню и только по ней раскрывалось ?

Comment: http://pro-potolok.com/potolki/ - вот рабочий пример. Совершенно верно, чтобы переходило и расскрывалось заодно. Пока только расскрывается. Переходит только по тем ссылкам, которые не задействованны в "раскрытии". Вообщем, надеюсь, понятно обьснила. Сомневаюсь, конечно, что такое возможно. В меню на jsfiddle есть плюсик/минусик слева (их не видно, не нашла как на jsfiddle картинки подключить, на моем сайте они справа), можно чтобы раскрывалось по клику на них, а ссылка сама была переходом.

Comment: просто уберите return false
[jsfiddle сегодня глючит, вот jsbin](http://jsbin.com/uZAqUXA/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: eicto, внимательней прочитала Ваш комментарий - в смысле и чтобы переход был по ссылке на определенную страницу, за которыю этот пункт отвечает и чтобы дочерние документы выезжали. Вот как-то так :)

Comment: ну то что я сделал не устраивает ? если ссылка не # то надо ajax мутить, либо не-js меню чтобы было.

Comment: в том то и дело, что ссылка обычная, типа http://pro-potolok.com/potolki/natyazhnyie-potolki/. Т.е. таким образом, как у меня и чуть подправить - это не возможно? Почему-то кнопка добавления комментария пропала, поэтому редактирую этот. А можно в качестве кнопочки для раскрытия/закрытия span использовать для +/-?

Comment: если к каждому полю кнопочку в виде отдельного элемента приделать, то можно. но лучше может по наведению сделать раскрытие меню, а по клику переход ?